# Adjective to describe a "basic" photograph

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a photo of a blue sky, showing the horizon and the water. It does not contain a complicated subject. I took it spontaneously and it is not that interesting. It is rather plain. I am looking for an adjective (plain or simple) which preferably does not have a negative connotation (not dull, for instance).

Would plain/simple/basic work or is there a better adjective?

Answer (score 1):

The thing that comes to mind first is a "typical country scene".

Example: https://uwispace.sta.uwi.edu/dspace/handle/2139/4741

However, I'm not sure if this is an apt description of your photo, because I don't quite know what your photo shows. Is it only the sky (maybe a few clouds here and there) and the sea? If so, it would make for a rather "plain seascape".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The following words express the required plainness adequately.

**Quotidian** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quotidian)) Having the characteristics of something which can be seen, experienced, etc, every day or very commonly; commonplace, ordinary, mundane.

**Prosaic** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prosaic)) (main usage, usually of writing or speaking but also figurative) Overly plain, simple or commonplace, to the point of being boring.

**Modest** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/modest)) Not bragging or boasting about oneself or one's achievements; unpretentious, humble.

You can also use "**routine**".

Comment: And you could call it *ordinary.*

Answer (score -1):

You might find the adjective "*banal*" proper, although it is mildly disapproving.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/banal?q=banal)) **banal** adjective
> /bəˈnɑːl/
> (disapproving)
> ​very ordinary and containing nothing that is interesting or important
>
> - a banal conversation about the weather
> - He knew how banal the question was as soon as he had asked it.
> - She murmured some banal phrases of encouragement.

Another possibility is "*artless*", which is not disapproving.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/artless?q=artless)) **artless** adjective
> /ˈɑːtləs/
> /ˈɑːrtləs/
> (formal)
> ​simple, natural and honest
>
> - the artless sincerity of a young child

([ref.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Birket_Foster/QIfqAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22artless+picture%22&dq=%22artless+picture%22&printsec=frontcover)) This artless picture with its wood - toy farm animals provides a delightful glimpse of the unformed style of Birket Foster , in which we can see an inherent sense of composition and hints of his adult manner , with a marked ability to ...

Comment: *"preferably does not have a negative connotation"*